# how can show image with titles in phonegap list?

Tags: html, list, cordova

my task is to display image with Titles in phonegap application

am successfully display list of Titles is ok code as

```
    $('#listview').append('<li id='+ids[i]+'><a    onclick="myFunction1('+i+')">'+titles[i]+'</a></li>');
```

the above code only display Titles but i have one array that conatins list of images i need display image with Titles

i tried this code it's not working

```
  $('#listview').append('<li id='+ids[i]+'><a    onclick="myFunction1('+i+')">'+images[i]+''+titles[i]+'</a></li>');
```

how can set this Titles as middle not like the post images ?![enter image description here][1]

Comment: What is the content of images array?

Comment: images[0] array contains 4cing.com/mobile_app/uploads/pageicon/friendship.png

Comment: @DZL  pls help me out from this problem i need display that url image into image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments to your question you need something like this

```
var images = ["4cing.com/mobile_app/uploads/pageicon/friendship.png"];
var titles = ["test"];

var imagesLength = images.length;  //cache the length property for performance
for (var i = 0; i < imagesLength ; i++) {
    $('#listview')
        .append('<li><a><img src="http://' + images[i] + '">' + titles[i] + '</a></li>');
}
```

CSS to vertically align the text would be

```
#listview a { display: block; }
#listview a img { vertical-align: middle; }
```

Comment: $('#listview').append('<li id='+ids[i]+'><a onclick="myFunction1('+i+')"><img src=http://"' + images[i] + '">'+titles[i]+'</a></li>'); is not working as per ur concept?

Comment: I made changes to my answer to accommodate your needs. You are not using img tag correctly. <img src=http://"' + images[i] + '"> should be <img src="http://' + images[i] + '">. Try this edited answer again.

Comment: perfect answer but output get like posted image ?

Comment: I don't understand what the question is?

Comment: k actually image is displaying perfect after display image see the Titles alignments ?

Comment: perfect solution..Thnkas dear @DZL